# Custom API length of time when calling issue

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, azure

I've wrote a custom API for a Scrabble Wordsolver it sends a word into all character permutations and returns a list of valid words.
I've tested it thoroughly on local host and runs well returning a list of words and definitions in about 2.5 seconds when a 7 letter word including a blank tile is entered  (roughly around 140000 character permutations).

The problem is when I push it live, when I make the call it takes around 15-20 seconds to return. Since it's not the code I don't know what the problem could be.

It's hosted with Microsoft Azure.

Would really appreciate any help I can get with this, I don't understand why the call is so slow.

Thanks

Comment: Depending on what scale of deployment you are using. The difference you are seeing might be your application be initialised on Azure. If you make more than one call, does the second one complete quicker?

Comment: No it doesn't, it still takes the same amount of time.

Comment: What scale is your deployment in Azure? Is it on a free/shared/standard plan? Bare in mind on your local your have your entire CPU to yourself, so doing complex analytics that use a lot of CPU will run a lot faster.

Comment: The plan is an S1 and it hosts multiple sites and databases,  It could be that it's fighting for resources which is something I never considered.

Answer (score 0):

If you're hosting this on a free / Trial account, it could simply be that your webAPI application pool is being recycled.

To verify, you can do a couple of 7-letter words in sequence. Do both take 20s or just the first one? If it's just the first one, then you have your answer. You can either do some "keep alive" stuff with it, or scale up to a production plan.

Comment: I'm using an S1 Azure account. The time don't change much on each call, milliseconds either way

Comment: I'm reading all English words in 15ms from a list of text files in blob storage, typically for another solution, but basically, looking to see if a word exists or not. Not sure why you're having such a bad timing. Are you processing in parallel?

Comment: No there is no parallel processing, The XML file I'm going through isn't on the blob but surely that won't be an issue?
Maybe I should upgrade Azure to see if it's any better?